# pgfplots : Row title in legend

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, legend

I would like to add a title to each row of my legend in pgfplots. I achieved this with this example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex, active, floats, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
     axis on top,
     axis equal image,
     xmin=-1, xmax=1.05, ymin=-0.05, ymax=1.5
    ,axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left
    , legend columns=3, legend style={cells={anchor=west}, at={(0.5,1)}, anchor=north, draw=none, name=legend_name
    ,width=\textwidth
    ]

    \addplot [color=blue, thick, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100]  {x^2};
    \addlegendentry{$x^2$}
    \addplot [color=blue, thick, loosely dashed, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {x^3};
    \addlegendentry{$x^3$}
    \addplot [color=blue, thick, dotted, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {x^4};
    \addlegendentry{$x^4$}

    \addplot [color=red, thick, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {2*x^2};
    \addlegendentry{$2 x^2$}
    \addplot [color=red, thick, loosely dashed, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {2*x^3};
    \addlegendentry{$2 x^3$}
    \addplot [color=red, thick, dotted, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {2*x^4};
    \addlegendentry{$2 x^4$}

    \end{axis}

    \node (legend_row_title) at (legend_name.west) [anchor=east, align=center, xshift=2pt] {1\textsuperscript{st} row :\\2\textsuperscript{nd} row :};
    \draw (legend_row_title.north west) rectangle (legend_name.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But the problem is that the anchor used to align the legend is the center of the legend itself so the rectangle and the row titles are bad aligned. Anyone know how to do it properly or at least to fix the alignment please?
Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
 \addlegendimage{empty legend}
 \addlegendentry{1\textsuperscript{st} row :}
```

to add a dummy legend at appropriate place:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex, active, floats, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
     axis on top,
     axis equal image,
     xmin=-1, xmax=1.05, ymin=-0.05, ymax=1.5
    ,axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left
    , legend columns=4, legend style={cells={anchor=west}, at={(0.5,1)}, anchor=north, draw=none, name=legend_name,draw}
    ,width=\textwidth
    ]
    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
     \addlegendentry{1\textsuperscript{st} row :}
    \addplot [color=blue, thick, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100]  {x²};
    \addlegendentry{$x²$}
    \addplot [color=blue, thick, loosely dashed, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {x³};
    \addlegendentry{$x³$}
    \addplot [color=blue, thick, dotted, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {x⁴};
    \addlegendentry{$x⁴$}
    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
    \addlegendentry{2\textsuperscript{nd} row :}
    \addplot [color=red, thick, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {2*x²};
    \addlegendentry{$2 x²$}
    \addplot [color=red, thick, loosely dashed, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {2*x³};
    \addlegendentry{$2 x³$}
    \addplot [color=red, thick, dotted, mark=none, domain=-1:1, samples=100] {2*x⁴};
    \addlegendentry{$2 x⁴$}

    \end{axis}

    %\node (legend_row_title) at (legend_name.west) [text width=4em,anchor=east, align=right, xshift=2pt] {\strut 1\textsuperscript{st} row :\\2\textsuperscript{nd} row :};
%    \draw (legend_row_title.north west) rectangle (legend_name.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for !
Thank you very much !